# Windows Phone 8 SDK running in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I know that the SDK is not finished, yet a few lucky developers have got their hands on it already, so here's my question: when you installing Windows Phone 8 SDK, did it install the SDK in Visual Studio 2010 also, or just on the 2012 edition (including 2012 Express)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After posting my question, two different developers that had access to the SDK contacted me directly stating that there is no integration of the Windows Phone 8 SDK in Visual Studio 2010, just on the 2012 version.

Comment: I can confirm that the WP8 SDK is only available for VS2012. (Oh, and I work for Microsoft)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, @ClausJørgensen

Answer (score 2):

No, You need Visual Studio 2012, Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise x64 + processor supporting SLAT for running Hyper-V.
You can now download the WP8 SDK here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471