# Wp8 SDK for vs2010 Professional version?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-8

can't we develop apps for wp8 with vs2010 professional version ?

can only find sdk for vs2012 [Link to WP8 SDk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, You can't.

**WP8 SDK is only available for VS2012 & There is no integration of the Windows Phone 8 SDK in Visual Studio 2010, just on the 2012 version.**

Look at the Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691553/windows-phone-8-sdk-running-in-visual-studio-2010)